# Trim pyaudio recording

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I am working on a project that involves getting audio input from the user and storing it for further processing. I have been successfully using `pyaudio` for this purpose. Now I began optimizing the code to limit the amount of content that needs to be transferred across the network, as well as stored on the server. Inspecting the audio amplitude graph there is nearly always a long waiting period in the beginning and/or at the end, with speaking in between. I want to detect and trim those uninformative sections of the audio file before saving it.

Here is an example amplitude graph; x axis represents the number of data points. In this audio more than 50% of the content is silent, hence should be trimmed/cut/removed. Note that short spaces during speech should not be removed.

[image]

My plan for the `trim_audio` method is to divide the range of x values to bins of, say, 10,000, and start iteratively removing bins from the two sides (i.e., from the left and the right) on the condition of whether the absolute value of amplitude is above the threshold 1000. If there is at least one data point in the bin with such a high amplitude level, the bin is kept and trimming is completed. So trimming is only performed until high-amplitude region is reached, both from the left and from the right. This ensures that inter-speech silent regions will not be removed from the file (such as the one that can be seen in the middle of the first graph above).

My problem with this approach is that it's very dependent on bin width. Let's consider the below plot (here amplitudes are already transformed to their absolute values); bin borders are represented by the vertical blue lines while the speech threshold is represented by the horizontal red line:

[image]

In this case the algorithm would trim the first six bins. In practice though, such tight trimming is not preferred, the audio file will sound strange, as if the very beginning of it was missing (which is indeed sort of the case, even with a low threshold). Surely I could just add one more logic that for the last bin to be removed, only remove half of it... but this wouldn't be a very sophisticated solution in my opinion.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this than what I envisioned. Since this is essentially signal processing, is there a signal processing library that could be used to tackle my problem?

My working code for recording:

```
from tracemalloc import start
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

audio_instance = pyaudio.PyAudio()

starting_time = datetime.now()
print("Recording started at ", starting_time)
stream = audio_instance.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16, channels = 2, rate = 44100, frames_per_buffer = 1024, input = True)

frames = []
while True:
    # If maximum allowed time is exceeded, quit loop and end recording.
    if datetime.now() > starting_time + timedelta(seconds=5):
        break 

    data = stream.read(1024)
    frames.append(data)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio_instance.terminate()
print("Recording finished at ", datetime.now())

def get_amplitude(frames):
    frames = np.array(frames)
    amplitude_array = np.frombuffer(frames, np.int16)
    return amplitude_array

def plot_audio(amplitudes):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,3))
    fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.plot(amplitudes)
    plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
    plt.show()

amplitudes = get_amplitude(frames)
plot_audio(amplitudes=amplitudes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've started working on something like this recently. I figured out that if you read a wave file using scipy.io.wavfile, you can access the amplitudes in the form of a list. In my case, I simply took a subset of the array in which its absolute values were below a certain value. The code I used is below and is reproducible with a wave file. In my case, I have a wav file that has two inputs (left and right) therefore the given amplitudes are presented in groups of two.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile

# Read the wave file
samplerate, data = read(path)

# Show length of data pre-processing
print(len(data))

# Frame Rate of Audio
print(samplerate)

# Taking amplitude values under absolute value of 50
trimmed_file = data[np.absolute(data) > 50]

# show the length of data post processing
print(len(trimmed_file))

# Writing Audio File to Given Folder
scipy.io.wavfile.write(export_folder + 'sample.wav', samplerate, trimmed_file)
```

This process works the same way for files with a single channel. This process can help you automate what you are trying to do without having to select a bin size. Hope this helps! I am attaching some images of the pre-processed wave file and what it looks like after post processing. Trimmed by file about a third of the size of the original.

[Pre-Processed Wave File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ5Ey.png)

[Post File Processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPDF0.png)